What writing sequence was used for double-sided papyrus scrolls?
This also determines the order in which one would read the writing on a double-sided scroll.  This question comes from reading the p52 fragment.

The text not in square brackets below shows what is written on the fragment (front 1st paragraph and back second):
[31 εἶπεν οὖν αὐτοῖς ὁ Πιλᾶτος· λάβετε αὐτὸν ὑμεῖς καὶ κατὰ τὸν νόμον ὑμῶν κρίνατε αὐτόν. εἶπον αὐτῷ ]οἱ Ἰουδαῖ[οι·] ἡμ[ῖν οὐκ ἔξεστιν ἀποκτεῖναι] οὐδένα· [32] ἵνα ὁ λ[όγος τοῦ Ἰησοῦ πληρωθῇ ὃν εἶ]πεν σημαίνω[ν ποίῳ θανάτῳ ἤμελλεν ἀπο]θνῄσκειν[. 33 Εἰσῆλθεν οὖν πάλιν εἰς τὸ πραιτώ]ριον ὁ Π[ιλᾶτος καὶ ἐφώνησεν τὸν Ἰησοῦν ]καὶ εἶπ[εν αὐτῷ· σὺ εἶ ὁ βασιλεὺς τῶν Ἰουδαί]ω[ν;] (John 18:31–33, NA28)
[37 εἶπεν οὖν αὐτῷ ὁ Πιλᾶτος· οὐκοῦν βασιλεὺς εἶ σύ; ἀπεκρίθη ὁ Ἰησοῦς· σὺ λέγεις ὅτι βασιλεύς εἰμι ἐγὼ εἰς τοῦ]το [γεγέ]ν[νη]μα[ι καὶ εἰς τοῦτο ἐλήλυθα εἰς τὸν κόσ]μον, ἵνα μαρτ[υρήσω τῇ ἀληθείᾳ· πᾶς ὁ ὢν ἐκ] τῆς ἀληθε[ίας ἀκούει μου τῆς φωνῆς. 38 λ]έγει  αὐτῷ[ ὁ Πιλᾶτος· τί ἐστιν ἀλήθεια; Καὶ ]τοῦτ[ο εἰπὼν πάλιν ἐξῆλθεν πρὸς τοὺς Ἰουδαί]ους[ καὶ λέγει αὐτοῖς· ἐγὼ οὐδ]εμ[ίαν εὑρίσκω ἐν αὐτῷ αἰτίαν. (John 18:37–38, NA28)
Considering how close the front and back passages are, I'm guessing they wrote a column on the front then the next column on the back, not the front at the beginning all the way to the end, then the back starting at the end all the way to the beginning.
I'm wondering if there are other papyrus fragments from double sided scrolls that would help determine this.  The preference was for scrolls to be single sided.

https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/epistles/

@Kris.  Thanks.  Looking at the damage to the papyrus manuscript at the link you gave, it looks obvious that the pages were in a codex form.

Papyrus scrolls were almost never written upon on both sides -- it would make the scroll very impractical to use. It takes two hands to manipulate a large scroll, and a scroll was only designed to be rolled up in one direction. It would be very challenging to navigate the scroll to read or write text on the outside of the roll--this would essentially entail using the scroll inside-out.
Isn't this an inefficient use of papyrus? Enter the codex. The codex was designed for convenient use of both sides of the page, and Christian writings are among the earliest adopters of the codex. P52 is from a papyrus codex.
Regarding the length of a line:

On a scroll the width of the column or length of the line of text -- the "stichos" --  was standardized by the ancient Greeks (since scribes were paid by the number of lines, the length of the line was very important to them). Stichometry is the counting of lines, and in the 19th century Charles Graux showed that the writings of Homer, recorded in 35-letters per stichos, appear to have set the standard generally adopted among Greek writers (Nouvelles Recherches sur la Stichométrie in Revue de Philologie, new series 2, 1878, pp. 97 – 143). So a scribe following this practice would write ~35 letters and then go to a new line. After reaching the bottom of the papyrus, a new column of the same width would be started.
On a codex this can be physically constrained by the width of the page, but the stichos was already pretty standard by the time the codex was invented.


Wow! I thought the codex form didn't appear until the 3rd century A.D,. but it actually appeared in the 1st century A.D.   https://www.bing.com/search?https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Codex#:~:text=The%20basic%20form%20of%20the%20codex%20was%20invented,in%20the%20suspension%20of%20papyrus%20exports%20from%20Egypt.
